# How to run a briefly running Docker container on Azure on a daily basis?

Tags: python, azure, docker, scheduled-tasks

In the past, I've been using WebJobs to schedule small recurrent tasks that perform a specific background task, e.g., generating a daily summary of user activities. For each task, I've written a console application in C# that was published as an Azure Webjob.

Now I'd like to daily execute some Python code that is already working in a Docker container. I think I figured out how to get a container running in Azure. Right now, I want to minimize the operation cost since the container will only run for a duration of 5 minutes. Therefore, I'd like to somehow schedule that my container starts once per day (at 1am) and shuts down after completion. How can I achieve this setup in Azure?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd probably write a scheduled build job on vsts\whatever to run at 1am daily to launch a container on Azure Container Instances. Container should shutdown on its own when the program exists (so your program has to do that without help from outside).

Answer (score 0):

[Azure Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-first-azure-function) has what you need to schedule daily tasks. In your case, you would select the Python runtime and schedule the job though Azure Portal (Select the Timer option)

Comment: he might have troubles delivering the code to the function, otherwise its a good idea